# Visual Basic Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a little Macro in excel. The Macro should take a double number from A1 and multiply this number by 5 and return it back into A1 but i always get error messages etc.

My code up to now:

```
Function multiply()
Dim a As Long
For a = 1 To 65563
cell(a,3) = cell(a,3).Value * 5
next a
End Function
```

I have not worked with VBA before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use function just use these subs:

bellow you can multiplay all of **column A ** values:

```
Sub example()
For a = 1 To 65563
Cells(a, 1).Value = Cells(a, 1).Value * 5
Next a
End Sub
```

considering 65563 CELLS isn't a good idea, i suggest you to use the sub bellow to count rows and reduce memory usage.

```
Sub example2()

Dim countrows As Long
   countrows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For a = 1 To countrows
Cells(a, 1).Value = Cells(a, 1).Value * 5
Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can i just overwrite my actual function with your "sub" or do i have to implement it in another way?

Comment: delete entire function, copy and paste these codes and put your cursor on each sub that you want to execute and then execute the code. remember your values must be in column A. if thes values is in different columns, edit A with other columns.

Comment: +1. For suggesting the use of `Sub` instead of `Function` and to avoid "HardCoded" Values :)

Answer (score 3):

That does what you ask, but it's a sub as you can't edit worksheet values using a function

```
 Public Sub multiply()
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim val As Long
    val = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = val * 5
    Exit Sub
 err:
 End Sub
```

Comment: +1 :) However 1 suggestion on error handling. put a message box in the `err:` to display the error message else the error handling is pointless as the user will not know if the code exits in between :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a macro for this - although if you do want to use VBA you can avoid time consuming loops altogether

**`1 Manual Method using Paste Special - Multiply`**

from [walkenbach](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip059.htm)

To increase a range of values by 5 times:

1. Enter 5 into any blank cell.
2. Select the cell and choose Edit, Copy.
3. Select the range of values (Column A in your example) and choose Edit, Paste Special.
4. Choose the Multiply option and click OK.
5. Delete the cell that contains the 5

**`2 Code using Paste Special - Multiply`**

Using Zack Barresse's code from [vbax](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=47) - with minor amendments

This code updates the selected range with a user-entered multiplier

```
Sub psMultiply()
    ' http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=47
    Dim y As Long 'The multiplier value, user-defined
    Dim x As Range 'Just a blank cell for variable
    Dim z As Range 'Selection to work with
    Set z = Selection
    y = Application.InputBox("Enter selection multiplier:", _
    Title:="Selection multiplier", Default:=10, Type:=1)
    Set x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If y = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Cancel button will = 0, hence cancel
    If x <> "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else: x.Value = y
        x.Copy
        z.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Kill copy mode
    End If
    x.ClearContents 'Back to normal
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it a little more generic by only multiplying the numbers you select:

```
Sub MultiplyByFive()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Selection
        cl = cl * 5
    Next cl
End Sub
```

This way you avoid the `65536` hard coding.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `Selection` Unfortunately Excel is not smart enough to understand what `Selection` is :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Interesting. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Definitely. As per Excel `Selection` means the last thing that is selected. It could be a shape as well. So if the user by mistake selects a shape instead of Col C then the code will crash. Similarly if the user selects a chart/Different Cell(s)/Different Column(s) then the user will not achieve what he wants to. Hence it is always advisable to specify what exactly you want to do. You can change your code slightly. For example Sub MultiplyByFive()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
      Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)
    For Each cl In rng
        cl = cl * 5
    Next cl
End Sub

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks. Good ideas in here about defensive coding.